# Close Explorer started as other user programmatically

Tags: c#, explorer, kill-process

Is it possible to kill the process `explorer.exe` which is started in my code as other user?

I don't have the permission to kill the process `explorer.exe`, because my code is running by the current user.

I have to run this as the user, which was used to start `explorer.exe`, but how?

```
Process[] pp = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
ArrayList processIDs = new ArrayList();


foreach (Process p in pp)
{
     p.kill();                
}
```

I also tried `p.CloseMainWindow()`. It closed the explorer window, but also the Windows shutdown window appeared. How do I prevent this window?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**ProcessStartInfo.UserName**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.username%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
 Process[] pp = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
 ArrayList processIDs = new ArrayList();

 foreach (Process p in pp)
 {
      if(p.StartInfo.UserName == "user name")
      {
           p.kill();
           break; 
      }
 }
```

Comment: Good answer, only try to provide more info on your suggestion. (I included a link to the used property, code only is often not enough to make the OP understand the subject)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to kill the process *explorer.exe* which is started in my
>   code as other user?
>
> I don't have the permission to kill the process *explorer.exe*, because
>   my code is running by the current user.

You've basically answered the question yourself. YES, you could kill *any* process started by *any* user as long as you (or the program which you run) have enough permission to do so.

> I have to run this as the user, which was used to start *explorer.exe*,
>   but how?

To do that you need to query the process (*explorer.exe*), get the user information that started the process, and use that user information to start your program. I honestly don't know if that's possible. The easiest workaround would be to run your program as **Administrator** instead of the user that started the process.

> I also tried `p.CloseMainWindow()`. It closed the explorer window, but
>   also the Windows shutdown window appeared. How do I prevent this
>   window?

You might wanna look at the following thread, it addresses the problem you're having:
[How do I progmatically close explorer?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3c89fe1c-d65a-4074-bdea-6836c1f05ffa/how-do-i-progmatically-close-explorer).

And here's the summary and the code to close all explorer windows, taken from the above link:

**P/Invoke declarations**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out IntPtr processId);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr hDesktop, EnumWindowsProc ewp, int lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern uint GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern uint GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, uint nMaxCount);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetAncestor(IntPtr hwnd, int gaFlags);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hwnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetLastActivePopup(IntPtr hwnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

const int GA_ROOT_OWNER = 3;
const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;

public delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);
```

**Close Explorer Windows**

```
static bool CloseWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
{
  if (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) return true;

  IntPtr processId;
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out processId);
  var process = Process.GetProcessById(processId.ToInt32());

  if (process.ProcessName != "explorer" || process.MainWindowHandle == hWnd)
    return true;

  var hwndWalk = GetAncestor(hWnd, GA_ROOT_OWNER);

  IntPtr hwndTry;

  while ((hwndTry = GetLastActivePopup(hwndWalk)) != hwndTry)
  {
    if (IsWindowVisible(hwndTry)) break;
    hwndWalk = hwndTry;
  }

  if (hwndWalk != hWnd) return true;

  // get the title of the window
  var maxLength = (int) GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
  var builder = new StringBuilder(maxLength + 1);
  GetWindowText(hWnd, builder, (uint) builder.Capacity);
  var title = builder.ToString();        

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title) && title != "Program Manager")
  {
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
  }

  return true;
}

static void CloseExplorerWindows()
{
    EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr.Zero, CloseWindow, 0);
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CloseExplorerWindows();
}
```